# Draw a frame or dialog inside another

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have seen this question a lot of times but nothing about wxpython

I am working on a project where I have to admin a remote application. I would need to access the look of the remote application. I there some simple way how I could show in my local application how the application looks.

Is it possible to export the rendered image to the buffer and/or then into an image that could be retrieved

Comment: Is it possible to draw a a frame or dialog directly inside a panel

Comment: Question: Is the remote application made by you and is it with wxWidgets too?

Comment: made by me. I have fuul control  over both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you last question, yes it is possible.

You can take a screenshot of your remote window as described [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/16/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-wxpython-app-and-print-it/)

I do not know how do you admin your remote application, but you can then send the screenshot via sockets or whatever you want.